# How to get a Cohort analysis using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6 period, 
       user_id FROM transactions
WHERE DATE(created_at) >= '2020-07-01' 
GROUP BY user_id, DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6
ORDER BY period
```

It returns a list of users that have had at least one transaction per period *(period === 6 days)*. Here is a simplified of the **current output:**

```
// res_table
+--------+---------+
| period | user_id |
+--------+---------+
| 0      | 1111    |
| 0      | 2222    |
| 0      | 3333    |
| 1      | 7777    |
| 1      | 1111    |
| 2      | 2222    |
| 2      | 1111    |
| 2      | 8888    |
| 2      | 3333    |
+--------+---------+
```

Now, I need to know, in which period, how many users have had at least one transaction again (in the term of marketing, I'm trying to picturing the retention rate by a Cohort chart). Therefore, the calculations must be done in the Cartesian algorithm; Like a `self-join`!

Here is the **expected result:**

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| periodX | periodY | percentage |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 0       | 0       | 100%       | -- it means 3 users exist in period 0 and logically all of them exist in period 0. So 3/3=100%
| 0       | 1       | 33%        | -- It means 3 users exist in period 0, and just 1 of them exist in period 1. So  1/3=33%
| 0       | 2       | 66%        | -- It means 3 user exists in period 0, and just 2 of them exist in period 2. So 2/3=66%
| 1       | 1       | 100%       | -- it means 1 user (only #777, actually #111 is ignored because it's duplicated in pervious periods) exists in period 1 and logically it exists in period 1. So 1/1=100%
| 1       | 2       | 0%         |
| 2       | 2       | 100%       |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

Is it possible to do this using MySQL purely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT first_period, period, COUNT(*),
       COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY first_period) as ratio
FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6 period, 
            user_id,
            MIN(MIN(DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)) as first_period
     FROM transactions
     WHERE DATE(created_at) >= '2020-07-01' 
     GROUP BY user_id, DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6
    ) u
GROUP BY first_period, period
ORDER BY first_period, period;
```

This does not include missing periods.  That is a little trickers, because you need to enumerate all of them:

```
with periods as (
      select 0 as period union all
      select 1 as period union all
      select 2 as period
     )
select p1.period, p2.period, COUNT(u.user_id)
from periods p1 join
     periods p2
     on p1.period <= p2.period left join
     (SELECT DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6 period, 
             user_id,
             MIN(MIN(DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)) as first_period
      FROM transactions
      WHERE DATE(created_at) >= '2020-07-01' 
      GROUP BY user_id, DATEDIFF(created_at, '2020-07-01') DIV 6
     ) u
     ON p1.period = u.first_period AND p2.period = u.period
GROUP BY p1.period, p2.period;
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as first_period FROM transactions WHERE DATE(created_at) >= '202' at line 5`

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . That was a typo.

Comment: `#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbname.transactions.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . This time, there is no syntax error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=effb0c794041cc22780bbc6c38e218e1.

Comment: You are really good in SQL .. One level upper than everyone .. Fully fluent in concepts and syntax ... Perfect ..!

Comment: One question, you've selected `ratio`, could you please tell me does it convey what thing exactly? Here's a result set of my real data https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4JAb.png

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . You can multiple by 100 if you want a value between 0 and 100.